# modulo OCI8 de phpinfo no se muestra sobre IIS

Tags: oracle, codeigniter, php7, iis

hice una aplicación en Codeigniter 3 que se conecta a una base de datos Oracle 11g. Desarrollo con XAMPP y la aplicación trabaja sin problemas, pero llegó la hora de desplegarla y el servidor destino es un Windows Server 2016 con IIS 10. Entonces Codeigniter es un framework basado en php, por tanto busqué un video en youtube que me enseña como [instalar y configurar php7 en IIS10](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gq3CpR4MOF4).
Todo bien por ahi, pero cuando el framework quiere usar el driver oci8 de php, me da el siguiente error:

```
A PHP Error was encountered

Severity: Core Warning

Message: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_11g' (tried: C:\php\ext\oci8_11g (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.), C:\php\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.))

Filename: Unknown

Line Number: 0

Backtrace:
```

entonces, cuando veo el phpinfo() del servidor, me doy cuenta que no esta el módulo OCI8.
Se que este módulo se activa en el php.ini, descomentando la librería a usar **;extension=oci8_11g**, aun asi no se me activa. He buscado artículos, tutoriales, videos, y nada me resuelve el problema. Por favor, ayuda.

El servidor es Windows Server 2016 con IIS 10.
La base de datos es Oracle 11g.
PHP es el 7.4.14 y Codeigniter es 3.1.11

Comment: El archivo dll está donde lo está buscando Codeigniter?

Comment: si te refieres a la dll necesaria para conectarse a oracle, no es de Codeigniter. La dll la pone PHP, php_oci8_11g.dll y esta dentro de la carpeta de php\ext. Creo que el problema radica en que php no esta viendo la instalacion de oracle database.

Comment: No. Ni siquiera logra intentar conectarse, el error lo dice claramente, no puede cargar la librería oci. La librería no está donde debe, no tiene los permisos correctos o no es la versión correcta. Y "la pone PHP" pero puedes revisar si reemplazándola por otra versión funciona

Comment: Le di permiso a la carpeta php entera y nada. Además, en una consola busque el camino **C:\php** (donde tengo la carpeta de php), y ahi ejecuté `php.exe -v` para ver la version de php, entonces, en el php.ini: si comento todas las extensiones (ponerle el ;) me sale `PHP 7.4.14...` como debería ser; si descomento **extension=oci8_11g** entonces me sale `PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'oci8_11g' (tried: C:\php\ext\oci8_11g (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.), C:\php\ext\php_oci8_11g.dll (No se puede encontrar el módulo especificado.)) in Unknown on line 0`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ya resolví el problema.
Sucede que el php que descargué era la version *Non Thread Safe* (como decía el tutorial de youtube que refería mas arriba), y la libreria **php_oci8_11g.dll** con la que estaba trabajando era para la versión *Thread Safe*. Luego que instalé PHP nuevamente (**VC15 x64 Thread Safe (2021-Jan-05 18:10:24)** en [windows.php.net](https://windows.php.net/download#php-7.4)), se conectó sin problemas.

Gracias a todos por compartir mi dolor de cabeza.